# Custom UIControl does not show up in toolbox

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement a custom control to have a reusable component that can be used in several view controllers. I followed this tutorial from Xamarin:

[custom controls](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/)

unfortunately the control does not show up in IOS Designer's toolbox. How can i make it showing up?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question:

The problem was that i needed to add a constructor like this:

```
    public YourControlClass(IntPtr p)
        : base(p)
    {
       ...
    }
```